# Android - Augmented Reality using METAIO

Tags: android, augmented-reality

I want to provide a service of augmented reality in my app using the location of the user. For example, if the user frames with the device's camera a monument, it must be provided a description on it.

- How can i implement it on an Android app?
- What framework I need to install?
- Where I can find a few examples showing the basic functions?

**EDIT**

Rather than display the information on the monuments framed by the device, i could simply show in which direction are located certain points of interest. But, given a certain direction (eg north), how can i determine what is in that direction within a certain radius?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to the question above by myself. I'm using Metaio for android! It is a powerfull tool which provides a lot of examples about Augmented Reality!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a whole field of study...

for example in Android, for implementing location you have to use the `LocationManager`.

To do the thing of the monument, you have to use iBeacon for Android for example.

Briefly, what you're looking for is "IPS - Indoor Position System". I dare to say this is not a place to ask for a "whole app projectation"

Good luck.